# How to uninstall a node js cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I have tried everything possibly I could think of. I recently created a command line utility and published it to github which somehow messed up my files. I need to know how to uninstall it. Here's what I've tried:

npm unlink

npm uninstall

checking System32 for related batch files

checking path environment variable

**Nothing** I've tried has worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed a package system-wide, you probably used the `-g` flag during installation.

So the uninstall command is: `npm uninstall -g thepackagename`

You can also try `npm remove -g thepackagename`